# Visual studio 2017 and nuget package

Tags: msbuild, nuget, visual-studio-2017, csproj

I am creating nuget package which should contain also config file. Problem is that if I want to use csproj for nuget package definition, I don't know how to specify that config file should be copied and "copy to output directory" on file set when package is being installed.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/guides/create-net-standard-packages-vs2017

Previously I used nuspec and for install.ps1.

Thanks
(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/guides/create-net-standard-packages-vs2017)

Answer (score 0):

To include a file, you need to add / modify an update item for the file. If you have set "copy to output directory" to "preserve newest", you might already have one in the csproj file. To include this file into the resulting nuget package, you need to set the `Pack="true"` metadata:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <None Update="config.txt" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" Pack="true" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Note that depending on your project type (=> web sdk or "normal" sdk is being used) you may see different item types (`None`, `Content`) for files.

Comment: But this did not copy the config.txt to project which installs this nuget package and does not set on copied file CopyToOutputDirectory. That's the goal.

Comment: this needs a custom nuspec at the moment. note that (even if the build action worked) the files are no longer copied to the consuming project's source code with NuGet 4 and PackageReference.

Comment: That's not very heplful. Many times some library provides some configuration or static files, which you want to modify. As they are not in the consuming project, that's not possible. And if you create own one with the same name, I expect it will be overwriten during build with the one from package.

Comment: Static files to be deployed with the consuming project is the new `contentFiles` feature (which cannot be used appropriately due to the GH issue i linked). But NuGet packages are no longer supposed to modify the source of the projects using them (adding content, executing scripts). They can bring in MSBuild props/targets though. It still works for `packages.config` based tooling but not for the new tooling options being developed.

Comment: For adding files to a project, templates should be used - either in VS or or through the new dotnet cli - e.g. `dotnet new MyLibConfig`.